# How can I match a text with colon using regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, match

I want to use regex to match any case with only 1 colon in front of a name or behind it, but not a name in between two colons.

Matches things like this:

```
name: | :name | name:`asdf`
```

But should not match any of these:

```
:name: 
eman: 
nnamee: 
:nameasdfj
```

I have a regex that I think covers all cases for the first three, but it also matches :name: which I don't want:

```
((?:^|\W)name:(?:$|\W))|((?:^|\W):name(?:$|\W))
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the match? Replace/extract/remove/count? Well, also, is `name` always a fixed string? If yes, try `(?<!\w):?name(?!\w)(?!(?<=:name):)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LYdn2l/1).

Comment: By your rules shouldn't `:nameasdfj` match? Assuming it should, and you just want to match valid instances of `"name"` you could use the regex `r':name(?!:)|(?<!:)name:'`, `(?!:)` being a *negative lookahead* and `(?<!:)` being a *negative lookbehind*. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d5QsNV/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `(?<!\S)name:|:name(?!\S)`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/hKL8bZ/1)

or slight boundry  use `(?<![a-z:])name:|:name(?![a-z:])`

[demo2](https://regex101.com/r/X7IFrc/1)

---

code sample using second regex

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = r'(?<![a-z:])name:|:name(?![a-z:])'
>>> content = 'asdf- name:'
>>> re.search(regex, content).group(0)
'name:'
```

Comment: Your regex can actually be shortened to `(?<!\S)name:|:name(?!\S)` as `:` is a non-whitespace character.

Comment: yeah `:` can never be a wsp

Comment: Any reason why this might work on regex101 but not in my actual python script? 
In my python script I have regex: r'(?<![a-z:])name:|:name(?![a-z:])' and then re.search(regex, content)

It works for the colon before but not something like this:
'asdf- name:'

Comment: re.search returns a match object, use the `group(0)` member to get some result. Added a code sample.

Comment: please upvote @user1094771 if you found this answer useful.

Comment: @Edward Thanks for the initial answer, but adding the group(0) still doesn't work for that case. The content is read from a file, so I'm wondering if that might affect it (even though it works for the :name case).